# Pandas scientific notation to Float

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I am conducting some mathematical operations on a pandas data-frame object. While doing this some of the attributes (with really small values) are being converted to scientific notation for eg :

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
 df_wip.x.astype(float).head()
```

[image]

I have also tried tinkering with the global settings:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:20,.12f}'.format
```

[image]

**Pandas version : 0.19.2**

Even writing it out to a text file gives me a scientific notation in it.

Need help in displaying the attributes as float and not scientific notation.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Apologies, just updated the question. I want to display the content in float format and not scientific.

Comment: You data has about 300 leading zeros, would you want to display 300 zeros in each cell? Why did you do `12f` not `300f` then?

Comment: My apologies, thanks for pointing that out I went ahead and rechecked my code. There was a calculation error in the logic. Thanks a lot for pointing out the obvious which I missed.

Comment: Your number is way to small .....almost equal to 0